# sympy3Dで、solveを使わないかっこいい方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: sympy, 数学

法線ベクトル?
中点?対称点の座標を求める【京大過去問】

(参考)法線ベクトルの求め方と空間図形への応用>記事の最後には、実際に京都大学で出題された「空間に存在する平面に対称な点」を求める問題を掲載しました。
https://linky-juku.com/normal-vector/
(参考)2006年度 京都大・文系数学 問2
https://www.densu.jp/kyoto/06kyotolpass.pdf#page=2

＜解説＞せっかくなので、これまで学習してきたsympyを利用してみました。

```
from sympy import *
var('x y z')
b = Point3D(1,3,7)
h = Plane((2,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,2)).projection(b)
print(solve([(x+b[0])/2-h[0],(y+b[1])/2-h[1],(z+b[2])/2-h[2]],[x,y,z]))
# {x: -5, y: 3, z: 1}
```

3行を、1行で(b,h,solve)解けますか？ よろしくお願いします。

Comment: かっこよくはないですが、`list(map(lambda a,b:b-2*(a-b), *Plane((2,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,2)).perpendicular_line((1,3,7)).points))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sympy import *
var('x y z')
b = Point3D(1,3,7)
h = Plane((2,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,2)).projection(b)
print(h+(h-b))
# Point3D(-5, 3, 1)
```